# Add CUSTOM data: patentTempId,TempId to Angular Tree node material

Tags: angular

I've a component: tree-node.component in angular 9 projects.
Now i want change data to bind tree nodes in this samples:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjvbyddbabd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

For example, i want add items to datasource tree node: ParentTempId,TempId.

data now is:

```
    const TREE_DATA = {
  Groceries: {
    'Almond Meal flour': null,
    'Organic eggs': null,
    'Protein Powder': null,
    Fruits: {
      Apple: null,
      Berries: ['Blueberry', 'Raspberry'],
      Orange: null
    }
  },
  Reminders: [
    'Cook dinner',
    'Read the Material Design spec',
    'Upgrade Application to Angular'
  ]
};
```

I want add item (PArentTempId,TempID) to Groceries node.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `TREE_DATA.Groceries.PArentTempId = [ 'TempId' ];` inside `initialize()` method before calling of `buildFileTree` method.